# JQuery | click function not working in Firefox, but working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have created an HTML file with a button. There is a JavaScript file which has code to print a message to the browser developer console when the button is pressed.

Everything works fine in Chrome but does not work in Firefox

I got some hits on SO regarding explicitly passing "event" as a parameter to the function associated with the action and I have done that, and still, I get no response from Firefox.

This is my JS

```
$("document").ready(function(){
        console.log('JS loaded');
         $("i.fa-trash-alt").click(function(event){
            console.log('Delete icon pressed');
        });
        })
```

This is my HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Playground</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></button>

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please advise if I have missed some step or if any additional information is required.

---

**UPDATE - WORKAROUND**

As a workaround, I have made the "delete" event link to the button and not the icon. This seems to be working in Firefox.

Comment: `$("document")` should be `$(document)`. The `document` is a global window object

Comment: Thanks for the tip @charlietfl

Answer (score 0):

I found following code is working fine. Would you please check it out.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Playground</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></button>

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function(){
        console.log('JS loaded');
         $("i.fa-trash-alt").click(function(event){
            console.log('Delete icon pressed');
        });
    }); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried and it's somehow not working for me. Just to be sure - it is not working only in Firefox. I have uploaded a video showing the same. [video](https://youtu.be/x0y4m2Obpc4)

Comment: it's working fine for me on firefox 66.0.2 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

You added click handler to the `<i>` tag which means you need to click on the icon. It's not the problem of Firefox, it won't work in chrome too if you clicked outside of the icon.

If you want to click outside the icon and be able to respond to click add click handler to the button rather than the `<i>` tag.

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    console.log('JS loaded');
     $(".btn").click(function(event){
        console.log('Delete icon pressed');
    });
```

Hope I answered your question.

Comment: I am already using that as a workaround as mentioned in my update section. However, that's not the original issue. I am clicking on the icon in both Firefox and Chrome. It's just not working in Firefox. I have loaded a video to show the behaviour [link](https://youtu.be/x0y4m2Obpc4)

Comment: I tried your code in firefox 66.0.2 (64-bit) and its working as I expected

Comment: Thanks @Rojen! That helped. I am on an Extended Support Release and the latest version for that is (60.6.1). I downloaded the same version as yours and it's working in there. So looks like a bug / lack of functionality in the ESR version. Will check with Mozilla on how to plan for this (as everyone in my company uses the ESR version).